# Bootstrap dropdown conflict with slider jquery ui

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

I have getting some problem in my OpenCart 2.3 project. Let me give you the brief.

In product listing page, basically `catalog -> view -> product -> category.tpl`, I'm using currency module and filter module.

See the image for reference

[image]

When I'm using the slider to filter my product list, it is refreshing the page data (note: here page is not reloading), but currency dropdown is not working.

If again I'm using the slider, then dropdown is working.

Means: after loading the page for the first time. if I am using slider, then for every odd turn, slider is working, for every even turn, slider is not working.

Now you have little bit idea about the problem.

Lets come to the coding part.

I'm in `module -> filter.tpl` file.
Here for slider this jquery is written

```
$("#slider-range").slider({});
```

In slider function, an object is passing, which is as follow:

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: <?php echo $min_product_price ; ?>,
    max: <?php echo $max_product_price; ?>,
    values: [ <?php echo $amount_min; ?>, <?php echo $amount_max; ?> ],
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> " + $("#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +"  -  <?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> " +
        $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1 ) );
        $('#amtmin').text('<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> '+$("#slider-range").slider("values")[0]);
        $('#amtmax').text('<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> '+$("#slider-range").slider("values")[1]);
      },
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#amtmin').text('<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> '+$("#slider-range").slider("values")[0]);
        $('#amtmax').text('<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> '+$("#slider-range").slider("values")[1]);
        $("#slider-range").val( "<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> " + ui.values[ 0 ] + "  -  <?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        filter = [];
        $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
              filter.push(this.value);
            });
        amount=[];
        var amtmin = ui.values[0];
        var amtmax = ui.values[1];
        amount.push(amtmin,amtmax);
        $('#amtmin').text("<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> "+$("#slider-range").slider("values")[0]);
        $('#amtmax').text("<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?> "+$("#slider-range").slider("values")[1]);
        window.history.pushState("","",'<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',')+'&amtmin=' + amtmin+'&amtmax='+amtmax);
        $("body").load('<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',')+'&amtmin=' + amtmin+'&amtmax='+amtmax);
        // window.location.href = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',')+'&amtmin=' + amtmin+'&amtmax='+amtmax;
    }
});
```

Focus in this line:

```
$("body").load('<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',')+'&amtmin=' + amtmin+'&amtmax='+amtmax);
```

This line of code is basically load a new url in my body tag, and note that, my header, my currency all are in body.
I dont know what is happening with this code. So that, one time currency dropdown is working, and another time not.

Also I want to say something, you can see the last commented line.

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',')+'&amtmin=' + amtmin+'&amtmax='+amtmax;
```

If I'm loading the new document (basically reloading), then everything is fine.

But i don't want to reload the page.
Can you guys help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please put your min and max price in below code

```
$this->currency->format((float)$min_product_price ? $min_product_price : $min_product_price , $min_product_price)

$this->currency->format((float)$max_product_price ? $max_product_price : $max_product_price , $max_product_price )
```

Note: you need to put these line at `controller/product/category.php`